# How to add multiple overlay?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 1 command to add gif overlay on video, and it works. Then I want to add a gif to the bottom right of the video and a logo in the middle left of the video. How can I do this?

My command:

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -y -i input.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i snow.gif -filter_complex "[0:v][ckout]overlay[out];[1:v]colorkey=0x000000:1.0:1.0[ckout]" -shortest -map [out] -map 0:1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 18 output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

## How to add multiple overlay

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -y -i input.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i snow.gif -ignore_loop 0 -i bottom_right.gif -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1:v]colorkey=0x000000:1.0:1.0[fg];[0][fg]overlay=shortest=1[bg1];[bg1][2]overlay=main_w-overlay_w:main_h-overlay_h:shortest=1[bg2];[bg2][3]overlay=0:(main_h-overlay_h)/2,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a? -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

See [overlay filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) and [How to add and position watermark with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10920872/).

## How to add audio filters to above command

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -y -i input.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i snow.gif -ignore_loop 0 -i bottom_right.gif -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1:v]colorkey=0x000000:1.0:1.0[fg];[0][fg]overlay=shortest=1[bg1];[bg1][2]overlay=main_w-overlay_w:main_h-overlay_h:shortest=1[bg2];[bg2][3]overlay=0:(main_h-overlay_h)/2,format=yuv420p[v];[0:a]asetrate=9.9/10*44100,atempo=10/9.9,lowpass=f=2500,highpass=f=400[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: thank llogan so much. it actived. tks u tks u.

Comment: Can you help me add a code that changes the sound frequency to the code above you wrote for me. this code "ffmpeg -i 12.mp4 -af asetrate=9.9/10*44100,atempo=10/9.9,lowpass=f=2500,highpass=f=400 output.mp4"

Comment: @GameReplay See updated answer.

Comment: thank you llogan. I got sick last week so now I receive your help. sorry if you are bothered, i want to zoom x1.2 video input.mp4 too, can you help me?

Comment: @GameReplay Super User is intended for 1 question per post. Distinct follow-up questions should be avoided. The zoom question should be a new, separate question.